# Python: network from dataframe

Tags: python

I have a dataframe `df` that contains the edgelist information of a directed network formed by nodes `i` and nodes `j`. Each node has its own `value`

```
df
    node_i    node_j    value_i   value_j
0    3         4          89         33
1    3         2          89         NaN
2    3         5          89         69
3    0         2          45         NaN
4    0         3          45         89
5    1         2          109        NaN
```

I would like to create a weight that is fraction between the value of the `node_i` and 'node_j', while the `NaN` should be replace by the average of the adjacent nodes.

I would like to have a dataframe like the following:

```
df
    node_i    node_j    value_i   value_j         w
0    3         4          89         33         89/33         ## fraction
1    3         2          89         NaN    89/((69+33)/2)    ## fraction with average
2    3         5          89         69         89/69         ## fraction
3    0         2          45         NaN        45/89         
4    0         3          45         89         45/89
5    1         2          109        NaN        109
```

I would make a loop but it is not efficient for large networks.

```
nodes = pd.unique(df['Node_i'])
df['w'] = 0
for i in nodes:
   tmp = df[df['Node_i'] == i]
   w_j = np.mean(tmp['Node_j']) ## Compute average
   tmp.ix[tmp.value_j.isnull(), 'value_j'] = w_j ## replace NaN with mean 
   idx = tmp.index()
   tmp['w'][idx] = tmp['value_i'][idx] / tmp['value_j'][idx]  )
```

Comment: I can't run your naive approach.  Can you post a desired output?

Comment: @user3483203 I did it